# pass argument into iframe src

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, src

I have two blocks of code

First:

```
function readJason() {
  var mainInfo = null;
  var _DATA_FOLDER = process.env.LOCALAPPDATA + '/dmv/dmv.data/cameraUrl.json';
  $http.get(_DATA_FOLDER).success(function(data) {
    mainInfo = data;
    var url = mainInfo.url;
    cameraDialog(url);
  });
}
```

Now `url` parameter holds `https://www.google.com` for example.

Second:

```
function cameraDialog(url) {
  $mdDialog.show({
    template: `<md-dialog class="fullscreen-dialog" layout="column"><iframe src='url' scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" style="position: relative; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
            </iframe></md-dialog>`,
  })
}
```

How can i insert `url` parameter into `src` ? (like the way i did it's wrong)

THANKS !

Comment: It looks like you are using the Angular Javascript framework. Please specify version number

Answer (score 1):

template(ES6/2015):

```
{
    template: `<md-dialog class="fullscreen-dialog" layout="column"><iframe src='${url}' scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" style="position: relative; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
            </iframe></md-dialog>`,
  }
```

Or

template(legacy):

```
{
    template: '<md-dialog class="fullscreen-dialog" layout="column"><iframe src="'+url+'" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" style="position: relative; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
            </iframe></md-dialog>',
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this instead :

```
template: '<md-dialog class="fullscreen-dialog" layout="column"><iframe src="' + url + '" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" style="position: relative; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe></md-dialog>'
```

Comment: Mark it as answer please